# Certain trigonometry packages from numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm writing code that solves the intersection of a few functions which involve cos and sin and other various trig functions in python.

But I feel like importing NumPy as a whole is too much of a load on such a small program, is there any other way to get basic trig functions and pi, without importing as a whole or is just specifying

```
from numpy import cos
from numpy import sin
...
```

the easiest and most economical way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sin`, `cos`, and `pi` are also in the [`math`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module.  So just:

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
```

No numpy required.

If you're using `sin` and `cos` on numpy arrays, it's better to use the numpy version, but otherwise, the ones from the math module are good.

Comment: easy enough, Do you know if it also includes pi?

Comment: Yes, it also includes `pi`.  I edited my answer to reflect this.